# Retrofit 2.0: how to generate pojo class for dynamic objects

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

[image]
How could I generate pojo class for above type of response.

I already tried http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and RoboPOJOGenerator

My JSON String is blow if you want to try.

```
{
"availableDates": {
    "2017-12-31": {
        "from": "08:00",
        "to": "17:00"
    },
    "2017-12-21": {
        "except": [
            {
                "from": "14:00:00",
                "to": "14:10:00"
            },
            {
                "from": "14:11:00",
                "to": "14:21:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I understood your question . You have a dynamic response from server where your keys might change. So in retrofit you have to statically provide Pojo classes from before. So you are stuck at this point. Typing an answer for you

Comment: Post your JSON in text format

Comment: try this http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: change your json response from back end make sure you will receive jsonArray instead of jsonOobject of pages

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that dynamically. Although you can parse such JSON using HashMap.

If you are interested to do that, use below syntax for page section

```
private HasMap<String, Page> pages;
```

It will parse JSON of pages into above HashMap. You will have "1", "2" etc as Key and Page as value for that.

---

As per you current JSON, solution would be

```
public class AvalDate {
  private HashMap<String, AvailableTimeSlot> availableDates;
}

public class AvailableTimeSlot {
  private String from;
  private String to;
  private ArrayList<ExceptTimeSlots> except;
}

public class ExceptTimeSlots {
  private String from;
  private String to;
}
```

Now you can read parsed values as

```
HashMap<String, AvailableTimeSlot> slots = avalDate.geAavailableDates();
Set keys = slots.keySet();
for (String date : keys) {
  // Here date is 2017-12-31
  AvailableTimeSlot avt = slots.get(date);

  // You can check if except available or not
  if (avt.getExcept() != null) {
    // Read array list of except for that day
    ArrayList<ExceptTimeSlots> except = avt.getExceps();
    // Do whatever you want to do with array
  } else {
    // you can read from and to directlly
    avt.getFrom();
    avt.getTo();
  }
}
```

Comment: As usual yes.. it will work... before that add getter setters into all 3 pojo. I did not added into code.

Answer (score 5):

1) Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

2) Paste your response over there and enter package and class name

3) Choose target language as Java

4) Source type as Json

5) Annotation style as Gson

6) Click Preview

7) Copy and paste those classes to your app package

Comment: i already tried did not generate proper POJO for my JSON String

Comment: buddy it will I am using that since I started development there must be something wrong

Comment: It will also create child classes if required you need pojo for that too

Comment: @VISH change your json response from back end make sure you will receive `jsonArray` instead of `jsonOobject` of pages

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Another buddy edited the answer please follow given steps to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Fellow eager-to-downvote-rookies-SO-users, I understand this is just a clarification, but I can't comment it, so here I go with the blessing of your down-votes.

**OP**, select these options in [this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/):
1) *Target language* as **Java**,
2) *Source type* as **JSON**,
3) *Annotation style* as **Gson**

and then try to generate the POJO classes.